# How to add qmake config in cmake or ros

Tags: qt, cmake, config, qmake, ros

i'm trying to convert a qmake project to CMake.
 How can i translate "CONFIG" to CMake or what is the CMake's way of using
 the CONFIG variable?

e.g. CONFIG += mylib

Comment: Is it Qt 4 qmake? You mean, something like CONFIG += serialport with the qmake prf file behind?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this: target_link_libraries(myexecutable mylib)

[Here](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.12/cmake.html#command%3atarget_link_libraries) you can find the documentation for more details.